# What is the best way to implement a read and write of a struct when you know the struct will change in the future?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, solid-principles

if I have a `struct A` that I know is not yet completely defined but I know that 'a' and 'b' are members of it and I need to write a function that reads and xml that populates it and writes it to an xml as it is now.

How can I write the read and write methods so that if someone in the future needs to add a member to `struct A` I can help him get an error saying that they also need to implement corresponding read and write that supports the extra member function?

```
struct A
{
  string a, b;
}

void read(A&);
void write(A&);

// in the future
// A becomes 
struct A
{
 string a, b, c;
}

void read(A&); // should give a useful error saying the read is outdated
void write(A&); // should give a useful error saying the write is outdated
```

Comment: There is no reflection in c++. You would need to explicit identify that members of `A`. Perhaps with an `std::tuple` of data member points.

Comment: Write binary format identifier before struct. Or look how it is handled in common serialization helpers such as protobuf, thrift.

Comment: There are different ways to serialize data in an extensible way. Depends on your use case. If space is not much of an issue, you could include a "version" field. That is how some serialization frameworks detect these cases.

Comment: @VTT You can't write a non-POD type's representation directly to a binary stream and hope to recover it.

Comment: You could have a look at Boost serialization: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.serialization They seem to have an option to write XML data, but I have not used it.

Comment: If you're not concerned that someone might *remove* a member variable, you could add something to `read` and `write` like this: `assert(sizeof(A)==12); // if this fails, this function is outdated; A has a new member variable that this code does not take into account. Please update this function.`

Comment: I guess it depends on the thing using the struct. So say `class Alphabet` is using `struct A`. I can make `struct A` just responsible for reading and writing itself. It would be easier future developer who is modifying `struct A` that it needs to write a corresponding read and write for itself. Maybe, I can let `class Alphabet` have a `struct AInteface` that can read and write. That way it is implementation independent from A's read and write.

Comment: Implement read and write as member function, make the data member private. Then make the free function forward their argument to the member function. The reason to be of member function is just that: make close together data and functions that depend on the data!!! This is the basis of OO programing. Just do it.

Comment: @Oliv I'm not quite clear on forwarding their argument. Can you give me a sudo code or something? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write a version or format number as the first item (maybe second item).

Read in the format number.

Determine how to read the remaining fields based on the format version.

Answer (score 0):

Just do Object Oriented programing, do not let data member accessible from outside of the class. This way each time you change the data member, you know that you probably have to reimplement all member function. This is the reason to be of object programming: putting close together function and the data they manipulate.

```
class A{
private:
  string a,b,c;
public:
  void read();
  void write() const;
};

// free function helpers:
void read(A&a){ a.read();}
void wirte(const A& a){a.write();}
```

Comment: But when deserializing data how do you decide whether it is outdated?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen That is the problem of the implementer of read and write methods! OO programming is just a tool to help us programming consistently, but indeed we still have to code.

Answer (score -1):

As you are primarily asking for patterns, I would make use of constructors inside structs. This keeps your codebase simple and anyone reading it can see the parts belonging together.

```
struct A 
{
    string a, b, c;
    A(a1,b1,c1) : a(a1), b(b1), c(c1) : { }; 
}
```

When you extend struct A by string d, you have 2 approaches:

1. extend the existing constructor,
2. add another constructor and leave the current one for compatibility

Regarding Read function: If your struct is somewhat private (in a class) you define a public function returning your struct 1:1 or you access your struct directly. You can also define a member function in the struct itself (syntax is similar to class members)

Reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: It's not clear to me how this answer addresses the core concern, implementing serialization and deserialization that accounts for new members.

Comment: you're right - this is not addressed. I tried to show up a way on how to manage and expand the struct. The serialization/deserialization needs to be done in user code. And there it needs to be verified that the structure has all required members.

Comment: honestly guys: He asked for "What is the best way to implement a read and write of a struct when you know the struct will change in the future?" - thats a possible answer on this specific question - really downvote?